# Windows store app: change background color of the Appbar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have an Appbar on my app and the background is white, any ideas how I can change this?
Here is my code:

```
 <AppBar>
     <Button       
    Style="{StaticResource HomeAppBarButtonStyle}" /> 
  </AppBar>
```

This gives:
[image]

But I want to change it to this:[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AppBar has a `Background` property. Use that property to set the color, for example by using a resource.

```
<AppBar  Background="{StaticResource AppBarBackground}">
```

AppBarBackground could be SolidColorBrush